# Logspout container in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to deploy logspout container in docker, but keep running into an issue which I have searched in this website and github but to no avail, so hoping someone knows.

I followed the following commands as per the Readme here: https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout

(1) `docker pull gliderlabs/logspout:latest` (also tried with `logspout:master`, same results)

(2) `docker run -d --name="logspout" --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --publish=127.0.0.1:8000:80 gliderlabs/logspout` (also tried with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, same results)

The container gets created but stops immediately. When I check the container logs (`docker container logs logspout`), I only see the following entries:

```
2021/12/19 06:37:12 # logspout v3.2.14 by gliderlabs
2021/12/19 06:37:12 # adapters: raw syslog tcp tls udp multiline
2021/12/19 06:37:12 # options :
2021/12/19 06:37:12 persist:/mnt/routes
2021/12/19 06:37:12 # jobs    : pump routes http[health,logs,routes]:80
2021/12/19 06:37:12 # routes  : none
2021/12/19 06:37:12 pump ended: Get http://unix.sock/containers/json?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

I checked docker.sock as `ls -la /var/run/docker.sock` results in `srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Dec 12 09:49 /var/run/docker.sock`. So docker.sock does exist, which adds to the confusion as to why the container can't find it.

I am new to linux/docker, but my understanding is that using `-v` or `--version` would automatically mount the location to the container, but does not seem to be happening here. So I am wondering if anyone has any suggestion on what needs to be done so that the logspout container can find the docker.sock.

System Info: Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396; Raspberry Pi 4 ARM 64, OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

EDIT: added comment about -v tag in step (2) above

Comment: It was a typo. I was using ```--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker/sock``` instead of ```--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock```. There went my 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The container must be able to access the Docker Unix socket to mount it. This is typically a problem when namespace remapping is enabled. To disable remapping for the logspout container, pass the --userns=host flag to docker run, .. create, etc.

Comment: Thankfully I did not have to do this. I found out there was a typo in the command I was using - ```docker/sock``` instead of ```docker.sock```, and I was constantly reusing the same command without typing a new one. Took me only 3 hours to figure it out. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Well you wrote something else. Glad it worked out for you pal.